# using MAX and COUNT together in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I'm new in mysql. I have 2 mysql tables, **company** and **info**. The 1st table has *cid, name, classification, address, city, phone, province* and the 2nd table has *cid, information dan infodate*. They are relational where company.cid=info.cid. I have used

```
SELECT *, MAX(infodate)
FROM company
JOIN info ON company.cid = info.cid
WHERE classification = 'Hotel'
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY MAX(infodate) DESC
LIMIT 0,7
```

I want to add **COUNT** in that statement so each company will have sum of informations to display. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What happens if you do this:

```
SELECT *, MAX(infodate), COUNT(*) as count
```

Comment: This query will return not consistent result set (as soon as `*` makes no sense in queries with `GROUP BY`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, MAX(infodate)
FROM company
JOIN info ON company.cid = info.cid
WHERE classification = 'Hotel'
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY MAX(infodate) DESC
LIMIT 0,7
```

And then, to retrieve the count use

```
$total = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()"));
$total = $total[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT company.*, COUNT(info.information) 
    FROM company JOIN info ON company.cid = info.cid
    WHERE classification = 'Hotel'
    GROUP BY company.cid
    ORDER BY MAX(info.infodate) DESC
    LIMIT 0,7
```

Comment: Even it works, the count is limited to 7. When you use LIMIT, the COUNT doesn't return all matching rows count.